# How to prevent passing id and password in url for a get call in web api C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, get

I have written a code to fetch details from active directory as a GET call based on user id and password. I am passing user id and password in the url like -http://localhost:1234/api/User/IsAuthorized/UserID=1234;password=qwerty
but this is an unsafe technique. Can anybody give me a solution to pass these values in the body and use it as a POST call instead of a get call
my code goes like-

```
   [Route("IsAuthorized/UserID={userName};password={password}")]

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IHttpActionResult GetIsAuthorized(string userName,string password)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;
        string errorMessage = null;
        bool hasError = false;
        bool isValid;


        UserDetails detail = null;
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "ABC"))
        {

            isValid = pc.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
            string token = null; 
            if (isValid)
            {                   


                detail = IsAuthenticated("abc", userName, password, out errorMessage, out hasError);
            }


            if (hasError)
            {
                detail = new UserDetails(isValid, userName, null, null, null, errorMessage, null);
            }
            else
            {
                if (detail != null)
                {
                    token = CreateToken(userName);
                    detail = new UserDetails(isValid, userName, detail.AssociateName, detail.Mobile, detail.Email, null, token);
                }
                else
                    detail = new UserDetails(isValid, userName, null, null, null, "unknown username or bad password", null);
            }

            return Ok(detail);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you think passing a password in a POST request is safe? It's still just plain-text...

Comment: @RB. It would not be exposed as in case of url

Comment: Um - that's really quite a minor detail - after all, the user who can see the URL is the one who entered it in the first place. Why do you even have to pass the password though? After all, the web-service is called "UserIsAuthorized" - surely you just need to pass the user-id in order to find out if a user is authorized?

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is that it sounds like your design is fundamentally flawed from a security perspective - it sounds like you are doing too much on the client-side, where the attacker has complete control.

Comment: Since you are in an Active Directory environment, your best option would be to use "digest authentication" - in this approach, only a token representing the users credentials is passed, and the token is only valid for a short period of time, which helps prevent replay attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even doing it like this? You must be calling you web api from a client. Why are you not using the HttpClient to pass your credentials to your api. Something like this:

```
public async Task<TResult> PostAsync<TResult, TInput>(string uriString, TInput payload = null) where TInput : class
    {
        var uri = new Uri(uriString);
        using (var client = GetHttpClient())
        {
            var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() });
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //Log.Error(response.ReasonPhrase);
                return default(TResult);
            }
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TResult>(json);
        }
    }

    private HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var username = //get username
        var password = // get password
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{username}:{password}")));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        return client;
    }
```